# Display popup message when the number of a group of cells equals number of another group of cells

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm looking for a script that displays a popup message when the number of yellow cells equals the number of red cells. I've include a picture of the concept below.  Any help is appreciated.

[image: example colored table]

Comment: jquery would be fine??

Comment: yes j query is fine. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the classes of your individual coloured blocks are `red_block` and `yellow_block`

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 var reds = document.getElementByClassName('red_block')
 var yellows = document.getElementByClassName('yellow_block')
 if(reds.length == yellows.length){
   alert("what ever")
 }
}, 1);
```

`document.getElementByClassName` will return an array of element having that class

Giving timeinterval to 1ms to check the values every moment

Comment: would I put the 1ms like this: setInterval(function(1ms). And where should I put the code? Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @TariqSherriff No you can't put that way. I have already set that to 1ms there. the syntax of setInterval is `setInterval(function(){}, interval)` interval is an integer only. don't put `ms` or `s` etc. Your function should come inside the `if` statement. you can change the if statement with your defined classes.(you can change red_block and yellow_block as per your code)

Comment: do you mind providing an example on jriddle i'll put in the code that i have now

Answer (score 0):

I've included the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var color = "White";
    $("#btnWhite").click(function () {
        color = "#FFFFFF"
    });
    $("#btnYellow").click(function () {
        color = "#FFFF00"
    });
    $("#btnRed").click(function () {
        color = "#FF0000"
    });
    $("#btnBlue").click(function () {
        color = "#0070C0"
    });
    $("#btnGreen").click(function () {
        color = "#00FF00"
    });

    $("table tr td").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });

});
```

```css
        body {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        label {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        input[type=button] {
            padding: 10px 16px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        p {
            margin: 1em 0 0;
        }

        td.pz {
            border: thin solid #000000;
            width: 59px;
            height: 57px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .red_block {
            border: thin solid #000000;
            width: 59px;
            height: 57px;
            background-color: #FF0000;
        }

        .yellow_block {
            border: thin solid #000000;
            width: 59px;
            height: 57px;
            background-color: #FFFF00;
        }

        td.padding {
            width: 59px;
            height: 57px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="btnWhite" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px dotted #999"
        value="">
    <input id="btnYellow" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FFFF00; border: 1px dotted #999"
        value="">
    <input id="btnRed" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FF0000; border: 1px dotted #999"
        value="">
    <input id="btnBlue" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #0070C0; border: 1px dotted #999"
        value="">
    <input id="btnGreen" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #00FF00; border: 1px dotted #999"
        value="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="yellow_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
            <td class="red_block"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Syam... I'm fairly new to scripting and I'm having trouble with getting this code to work. Could you please tell me where to insert the function and test it for me. I've included my code above. Your support is greatly appreciated.